# Is it possible to query a database based on it's __str__?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Let's say theoretically I have these 3 models:

```py
    class Cable(models.Model):
        id = models.OneToOneField(Item, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        type = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.cableTypes, default=1)
        notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
        length = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.get_type_display()) + " Cable, " + str(self.length) + "m"


    class Adapter(models.Model):
        id = models.OneToOneField(Item, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        adaptFrom = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.connectors, default=1)
        adaptTo = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.connectors, default=1)
        notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
        length = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.get_adaptFrom_display()) + " to " + str(self.get_adaptTo_display())


    class Fixture(models.Model):
        id = models.OneToOneField(Item, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        type = models.IntegerField(choices=choices.fixtureTypes, default=1)
        model = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=128)
        manufacturer = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=128)
        notes = models.TextField(blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.manufacturer) + " " + str(self.model)
```

Is it possible to query these models based on the string they return? If not, how would I go about doing something similair to it?

The reason I need to do this is because I have a parent model called item (which is where all of these models get their primary keys from) but I still need to implement a search function to my website.

Here is my current way of doing it, which is a bit messy:

```py
    results = []
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for category in Type.objects.all():
                for item in Item.objects.all():
                    if item.type == category:
                        model = apps.get_model("dashboard", model_name=category.name.lower())
                        itemreferenced = model.objects.get(id=item.id)
                        if form.cleaned_data["query"] in str(itemreferenced).lower():
                            results.append(itemreferenced)
        context["searchResults"] = results
```

Comment: you could add column to database with this string and then you can use it in SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.annotate()` a query with a concatenation of various fields and then `.filter()` on that new field:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Cable.objects.annotate(
    description=Concat(
        'type', Value(" Cable, "), 'length', Value("m"),
        output_field=CharField()
    ).filter(
       description__icontains=query
    )
)
```